# У меня не получается восстановить состояние RecyclerView после поворота экрана

Tags: android, recyclerview, kotlin

на stackoverflow ([ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816217/how-to-save-recyclerviews-scroll-position-using-recyclerview-state)) нашел способ сохранения состояния RecyclerView. Сохранения происходит, а вот возобновление после поворота экрана нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В конце гифки видно, что после поворота я вызываю метод загрузки данных и вызываю метод RecyclerView обновить список. Если я этого делать не буду, я получаю белый экран.

Ранее я делал по другому. Сохранял массив и позицию скролла.

```
class BookmarkActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ViewBookmark{

    private lateinit var viewAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
    private lateinit var viewManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

    private val presenter : PresenterBookmark
    private val arrayList: ArrayList<BookmarkList>

    private lateinit var progressBar : ProgressBar



    companion object {
        val TAG = "BookmarkActivity"
        val LIST_STATE_KEY = "bookmark_list"
    }
    init {
        arrayList = ArrayList()
        presenter = PresenterImpl(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate(@Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bookmark)

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBarBookmark)
        recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_bookmark)
        viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        viewAdapter = BookmarkAdapter(this)

        recyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager = viewManager
            adapter = viewAdapter
        }

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            presenter.getData()
            removeList()
        }

    }


    override fun getRepositoriesRowsCount(): Int = presenter.getSizeData()

    override fun currentListPosition(position: Int): Int = presenter.setCurrentListPosition(position) 

    override fun getItemViewHolder(rowView: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) = presenter.setItemViewHolder(rowView, position)

    override fun progressBarGone() {
        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    override fun removeList() {
        recyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun stopScroll() {
        recyclerView.stopScroll()
    }



    public override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        Log.d("onSaveInstanceState", "Save -----")
        outState!!.putParcelable(LIST_STATE_KEY, recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState());
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Log.d("onRestoreInstanceState", "Restore YES-----")
            val savedRecyclerLayoutState : Parcelable = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(LIST_STATE_KEY)
            recyclerView.layoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(savedRecyclerLayoutState)

            progressBarGone()
            presenter.getData() // ЗАГРУЖАЮ ДАННЫЕ СНОВА
            removeList() //ВЫЗЫВАЮ   recyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно порядок в onCreate должен быть всегда такой:

- загружаем данные всегда (если presenter сохранился в статическом компаньоне то они сразу появятся)
- далее у нас есть сохраненный bundle устанавливаем из него позицию.

Т.е. теперь у вас для данных кэширование в презентере (а он уже решает кэшировать или забирать новый из модели)

Comment: Здравствуйте, я так понял что ссылку на presenter нужно объявить в companion?

Comment: У меня таким образом получилось сохранить состояние, и появилась другая проблема, я же теперь  в presenter передаю старую ссылку на активити, поэтому новые данные не приходят. То есть они обработаны и отправлены, только уже в старое активити.

Comment: По хорошему, презентер должен:
- хранить Weak ссылку на активити
- также после пересоздания вы должны посылать в Presenter новую версию активити

Вообще сейчас Google продвигает MVVM когда слой VM не имеет ссылку на вью, а вью всегда подписывается сама с учетом lifecycle https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/

Comment: Я не знаю как передать слабую ссылку, впервые слышу. Но вы мне помогли, всё работает. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если вы так-же боретесь с этой проблемой, вот мое решение.

```
class BookmarkActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ViewBookmark{

    private lateinit var viewAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
    private lateinit var viewManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var progressBar : ProgressBar

    override fun onCreate(@Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bookmark)

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBarBookmark)
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_bookmark)
        this.viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        viewAdapter = BookmarkAdapter(this)

        recyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager = viewManager
            adapter = viewAdapter
        }
        if(presenterImpl == null) {
            presenterImpl = PresenterImpl(this)
            presenterImpl?.getData()
        }else{
            progressBarGone()
        }
    }

    override fun getRepositoriesRowsCount(): Int = presenterImpl!!.getSizeData() //Возвращает размер массива.

    override fun currentListPosition(position: Int): Int = presenterImpl!!.setCurrentListPosition(position) //Возвращает индекс шаблона ViewHolder

    override fun getItemViewHolder(rowView: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) = presenterImpl!!.setItemViewHolder(rowView, position)

    override fun progressBarGone() { progressBar.visibility = View.GONE }

    override fun removeList() {  recyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() }

    override fun stopScroll() {
        recyclerView.stopScroll()
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Log.d("onRestoreInstanceState", "Restore -----")
            /* Если ссылка презентер был ранее сохранена в companion object, мы должны presenter
             * сообщить новую ссылку на ViewBookmark, иначе данные будут уходит на старую ссылку.
             * Так же можно избавиться от переопределенного метода onRestoreInstanceState, а метод presenter
             * onConfigurationChanged вызывть в блоке else, метода onCreate. */
            presenterImpl!!.onConfigurationChanged(this)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val TAG = "BookmarkActivity"
        var presenterImpl : PresenterImpl? = null
    }
}
```

Спасибо за помощь пользователю под ником Serge Markov.